# Running Spring Boot docker instance with Postgres docker instance

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I'm attempting to run a Spring Boot app that connects a Postgres DB using:

docker-compose.yml (for Postgres) :

```
  version: '3'
  services:
  postgres-db:
  container_name: postgres-db
  image: postgres:latest
  restart: always
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: my_user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
  POSTGRES_DB: shorten-db
```

To run the Postgres DB:

```
docker-compose up
```

.Dockerfile (for the Spring Boot app) :

```
  FROM openjdk:12-jdk-alpine
  RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
  USER spring:spring
  ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
  COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

In order to run the Spring app using Docker I use:

```
  mvn package
  
  docker build -t url-shorten/url-shorten-docker .
  
  docker run -p 8080:8080 url-shorten/url-shorten-docker
```

But I receive the error when starting when running above docker command:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

In Spring application.properties I connect to the DB using:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shorten-db
```

I think this error is due to the Spring Boot app is running in a different container to DB so it cannot find the DB on `localhost`. Is there an idiomatic way of connecting the Spring Book docker container to the DB container. Or do I have do access the IP address of my machine and use this address to connect to the Postgres DB running on Docker?

Comment: If you're running a container in the same network, it can be accessed by its container name, e.g. postgres-db:5432

Comment: The answers that you got (to use the container name `postgres-db` directly) will work only if you run the containers at the same `user-defined` bridge. The way you are doing it now, the db container runs at the bridge created automatically when you `docker-compose up` and the other (with `docker run ...`) will run at the `default` bridge.

Comment: More here: [Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

Comment: @tgogos so I need to create a bridge using: "docker network create my-net" then specify the bridge my-net in the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: I would put the Spring-boot container details inside the `docker-compose.yaml` file and let docker-compose deal with the networking. When you `docker-compose up` / `down` it creates/deletes automatically a custom bridge for your convenience. Check more here: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: The other option is what you are proposing, yes, to deal with the networks yourself a little bit more "manually".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't use localhost in this situation

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/shorten-db
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring `application.properties`, try to change DB config to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/shorten-db
```

In container networks, You need to use the container name as a host.

Answer (score 0):

You can add both DB and app containers to one Docker network and change PostgreSQL host in datasource URL to `postgres-db`. Then Spring app will work with your DB.